# trigger Ajax and refresh table at the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have table like this below.

This table shows the contend of database.

```
<table>
<tbody id="2"><tr><td>name1</td><td><a href="javascript:del(2)"><span>del</span></a></td></tr></tbody>
<tbody id="6"><tr><td>name2</td><td><a href="javascript:del(6)"><span>del</span></a></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

'del' link calls the Ajax and delete item from database.

```
function del(num){
  $.post('{{path('acme_member_delScore')}}',              
    {data1: num },     function(response){
        if(response.code == 100 && response.success){//dummy check
          //do something
           var tbody = document.getElementById(num);
           var tr // i want to get tr
           tbody.removeChild(tr);  

        }
  }, "json");
}
```

How can I refresh table?

Comment: place the code to run within the ajax success: function

Comment: why you want to keep tbody anyways when you are deleting the tr under it and it will remain empty, you rather remove the tbody. `$("#"+num).remove();`

Comment: thanks it is good answer for dynamic variable using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice not to use two tags for links. Use only one:

```
<table>
<tr><td>name1</td><td><span data-del="2">del</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>name2</td><td><span data-del="6">del</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Do all in one handler. And use "closest" to find parent TR:

```
$('span[data-del]').click(function(){
  var obj = $(this);
  var num = $(this).attr('data-del');
  $.post('{{path('acme_member_delScore')}}',              
    {data1: num }, function(response){
    if(response.code == 100 && response.success){
      obj.closest('tr').remove();
    }
  }, "json");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({url: {{path('acme_member_delScore')}}, type: "post",
data: { data1: num },
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
// run code here to refresh table
}, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
//run code here to display error
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is , Anyway the table generating dynamically when loads from database. So set id for the tr like

```
<table>
<tr id="tr_2"><td>name1</td><td><a href="javascript:del(2)"><span>del</span></a></td></tr>
<tr id="tr_6><td>name2</td><td><a href="javascript:del(6)"><span>del</span></a></td></tr>
</table>
```

So that in Ajax itself you can delete the tr by

```
function del(num){
  $.post('{{path('acme_member_delScore')}}',              
    {data1: num },     function(response){
        if(response.code == 100 && response.success){//dummy check
          //do something
          $("#tr_"+num).remove();
        }
  }, "json");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try put remove code in post function.

Then it will be something like :

```
function del(num){
$.post('{{path('acme_member_delScore')}}',              
    {data1: num },     function(response){
        if(response.code == 100 && response.success){//dummy check
          $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        }
  }, "json");
}
```

But normally we don't do like this.

Normally when loading data, we append an id into the  tag. Say,

```
<tr><td>name1</td><td><a href="javascript:del(2)"><span>del</span></a></td></tr>
```

let's say if we have the id of name1 in database, we could append id='name-1' (and id='del-1' for delete button as well). Then it will be easier for you to manipulate tr tags. The code will kind look like:

```
$('#del-1').click(function() {
$.post('{{path('acme_member_delScore')}}',              
    {data1: num }, function(response){
        if(response.code == 100 && response.success){//dummy check
          //parse the id, get the index. 
          $('#name-1').remove();
        }
  }, "json");
});
```

===================================
As long as you can get the id in script, you can get the element like this

```
var tempId = '#name-' + 1;
$(tempId).remove();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see thanks,but I want to decide name-1 with variable dynamically such as $('#{{num}}')  (num is variable) how can I make it?